# получить SHA-1 APK файла по имени пакета

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Здравствуйте столкнулся с проблемой: нужно получить SHA-1 APK-файла заданного приложения, я могу получить пакет, версию, имя, но вообще не могу понять как получить SHA-1, сделать это нужно прямо на телефоне посредством вызова метода из приложения.

```
val packageList  = context?.getPackageManager()?.getInstalledPackages(0)

val packageInfo : PackageInfo = packageList.get(i)

Log.d("qwertyuiop","versionName: " + packageInfo.versionName) // Версия
Log.d("qwertyuiop","packageName: " + packageInfo.packageName)  // имя пакета.
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как получить SHA-1 APK файла, потому что этот вопрос не гуглится, заранее спасибо!

UPD:

```
for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md;
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());  // это и будет SHA-1?
        String hash_key = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
    }
```

Comment: У меня по запросу `android get sha1 programmatically` вот такое выдаёт, например: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28408600/3212712

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не смог найти это решение, спасибо, не подскажите в одном из примеров  есть код которым я обновил вопрос, я правильно указал где будет SHA-1? И что тогда из себя представляет String hash_key?

Comment: Надо запускать и смотреть что получится) Но, вроде, то что вам надо будет как раз в hash_key

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Благодарю!